# Remove drive model from partition labels in left pane

Tags: pantheon-files

Nitpicking I know, but since upgrading to 7.1, Files has started showing partitions with drive model numbers like this:
[image]

Anyone know how to get rid of this irrelevant and screen estate gobbling irritation?